# Rendering issues with chrome

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, mybb

I got this site in chrome the top right menu has question marks after every li except the last. This does not appear in any other browser....

[image: q marks]

What is causing the question marks?

Comment: I do [not see any questionmark](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jBjph.png). Post the relevant code on Stack Overflow. Currently, the question (&answer) is only useful to you, which is a perfect reason for closing the question as Too localised - see [faq].

Comment: hmmm, your screenshot is from Chrome? this is mine http://i.imgur.com/jRRNu.png

Comment: Most recent chrome to, in case you are wondering. Firefox and Ie on the same machine does not cause this. I tested it on 6 different pc's (friends and families) we all get the question mark....

Comment: In future, please 1) provide the image up front and 2) post the relevant HTML.  Questions that require users to visit your website in order to debug it aren't allowed and will be closed as "too localized"  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try some other font (other than Comfortaa) will fix the issue.

Comment: Get rid of font-family: 'Comfortaa' try some other font will fix the issue.

Comment: Yup, this seems to be it... set the font family of the ul to arial and for the li to comfortaa ;)

Comment: That still leaves a question mark in "Members List", but removes them between the menu items at least. It seems that Chrome can't find the font's space character, and instead subs in the question mark.

Comment: You suggestion to use another font other then comfortaa works perfect. This is a theme for mybb that another person created. I was suggested to link to the google web fonts directly, instead of using font squirrel like the theme already had set up. I have notified the original creator of this issue so he may fix it in later releases.